# Getting NULL after create external table in Hive using parquet file as storage

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am creating external table in Hive using parquet file as a storage

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_data(
      c1 string, c2 int, c3 string, c4 string, c5 string, c6 float,
          c7 string, c8 string, c9 string, c10 string, c11 string, c12 string)
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
        STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat'
        LOCATION '/path/test_data/';
```

selecting this table getting NULL in any rows and columns

```
SELECT * FROM test_data;
OK
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.191 seconds, Fetched: 34 row(s)
```

I've got parquet file by Pig transformation from tab delimeted file using following sequence

```
grunt> A = LOAD '/path/test.data' USING PigStorage('\t')
        AS ( c1: chararray,c2: int,c3: chararray,
             c4: chararray,c5: chararray,c6: float,
             c7: chararray,c8: chararray,c9: chararray,
             c10: chararray, c11: chararray, c12: chararray );
grunt> STORE A INTO '/path/test_data' USING parquet.pig.ParquetStorer;
```

To check up that the parquet file contains valid data read it back

```
grunt> B = LOAD'/path/test_data' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader;
grunt> DUMP B;
(19,14370,rs6054257,G,A,29.0,PASS,NS=3;DP=14;AF=0.5;DB;H2,GT:GQ:DP:HQ,0|0:48:1:51,51,1|0:48:8:51,51,1/1:43:5:.,.)
(20,17330,.,T,A,3.0,q10,NS=3;DP=11;AF=0.017,GT:GQ:DP:HQ,0|0:49:3:58,50,0|1:3:5:65,3,0/0:41:3)
(20,1110696,rs6040355,A,G,T,67.0,PASS,NS=2;DP=10;AF=0.333,0.667;AA=T;DB,GT:GQ:DP:HQ,1|2:21:6:23,27,2|1:2:0:18,2,2/2:35:4)
(20,1230237,.,T,.,47.0,PASS,NS=3;DP=13;AA=T,GT:GQ:DP:HQ,0|0:54:7:56,60,0|0:48:4:51,51,0/0:61:2)
(20,1234567,microsat1,GTC,G,GTCTC,50.0,PASS,NS=3;DP=9;AA=G,GT:GQ:DP,0/1:35:4,0/2:17:2,1/1:40:3)
(20,2234567,.,C,[13:123457[ACGC,50.0,PASS,SVTYPE=BND;NS=3;DP=9;AA=G,GT:GQ:DP,0/1:35:4,0/1:17:2,1/1:40:3)
(20,2234568,.,C,.TC,50.0,PASS,SVTYPE=BND;NS=3;DP=9;AA=G,GT:GQ:DP,0/1:35:4,0/1:17:2,1/1:40:3)
(20,2234569,.,C,CT.,50.0,PASS,SVTYPE=BND;NS=3;DP=9;AA=G,GT:GQ:DP,0/1:35:4,0/1:17:2,1/1:40:3)
(20,3234569,.,C,<INV>,50.0,PASS,SVTYPE=BND;NS=3;DP=9;AA=G,GT:GQ:DP,0/1:35:4,0/1:17:2,1/1:40:3)
(20,4234569,.,N,.[13:123457[,50.0,PASS,SVTYPE=BND;NS=3;DP=9;AA=G,GT:GQ:DP,0/1:35:4,0/1:17:2,./.:40:3)
(20,5234569,.,N,[13:123457[.,50.0,PASS,SVTYPE=BND;NS=3;DP=9;AA=G,GT:GQ:DP,0/1:35:4,0/1:17:2,1/1:40:3)
(Y,17330,.,T,A,3.0,q10,NS=3;DP=11;AF=0.017,GT:GL,0:0,49,0:0,3,1:41,0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: posting it on hive user group user@hive.apache.org might be a better option.

Comment: I'm running in to a same problem. But the same query works fine in Impala!!!

Answer (score 6):

In my case it seemed that Hive was sensitive to column names.

Having exported my parquet file from a dataframe in Spark, I had to use the exactly the same column name in Hive as I had in the Spark dataframe originally.

When I used generic column names such as `c1` I'd get `NULL` values for all values in that particular column.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, HDFS file was in comma delimited format, I was not defining row format delimited in command. Like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TABLENAME(COL1 INT, COL2 STRING....) LOCATION '/user/....';
```

it used to create table with same number of rows but with all values as null. I modified above command as follows and it works as charm:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TABLENAME (COL1 INT, COL2 STRING....) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION '/user/.....';
```

Answer (score 4):

I too faced similar issues.

- The main cause of this issue is **Schema mismatch**. First check the Schema of the parquet file you are using. If it is an output of a process, it has a _metadata or related metadata file. Open and see the column **names and types**. Creating table based on this schema would help a lot!
- Also check the compression format (Snappy,GZIP) and provide in `TBLPROPERTIES ('PARQUET.COMPRESS'='GZIP')`
- I faced similar issue when I had to use Parquet file persisted from spark Dataframe. The column names were different from the table I created, and I got all NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_data(
      c1 string, c2 int, c3 string, c4 string, c5 string, c6 float,
          c7 string, c8 string, c9 string, c10 string, c11 string, c12 string)
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
        **WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
    ("casesensitive"="c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12")**
        STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat'
        LOCATION '/path/test_data/'